# MD5 Password login is not working laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to change my password field bcrypt to md5. In database i am storing password in md5 but login is not working

myController:

```
 public function postLogin(Request $request)
 {
    $this->validate($request, array('username' => 'required', 'password' => 'required'));
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::validate($credentials)) 
    {
        $user = Auth::getLastAttempted();
        Auth::login($user, $request->has('remember'));
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
      ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
      ->withErrors([
          'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
        ]);

}
```

Comment: Not sure why you would want to use md5 for passwords anymore. Seems like a mistake to me.

Comment: Don't do that. MD5 is considered unsuitable for security purposes and bcrypt (with a sufficient cost) is far superior.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a custom user provider to do this since Laravel's default user providers rely on `bcrypt`. The documentation for this is here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers

*However*, the reality is that you do not want to do this. MD5 is totally inadequate for password hashing - Laravel has built in hashing which is far more secure and you should really be using that.

Answer (score 0):

use md5 while getting password from field and check it with database md5 password.

example:

```
$passs=md5($request->password);
$username=$request->username;
$adminPass=$user->select('password')->where('user','=',$username)->first();
if($passs===$adminPass){
   // redirect
}
```